# how to insert BUTTON value in to database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Hi I'm trying to insert the value of the button into the code:

Here is the code for button:

```
<asp:Button ID="addFriend" runat="server" ' CommandArgument ='<%# Eval("ProfileId") %>' 
     CommandName='<%# Eval("ProfileId") %>'  Value='<%# Eval("ProfileId") %>Text="Add Friend" 
     CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClick="addFriend_Click" />
```

Here is the code for insert:

```
    protected void addFriend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the UserId of the just-added user
        MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
        Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;
        var addFriend = sender as Button;
        var value = addFriend.Text;


        // Insert a new record into UserPro
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        string insertSql = "INSERT INTO User_Friend(ProfileId1, ProfileId) VALUES (@FriendProfileId, (SELECT ProfileId FROM User_Profile WHERE UserId = @UserId))";

        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FriendProfileId", addFriend.Text);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", currentUserId);

            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

It works, but it inserts the button text and not the value.

Comment: I think you have used the button text to save in your parameter as **addFriend.Text** instead you should have **addFriend.Value**.

Answer (score 2):

The [asp:Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button(v=vs.110).aspx) class has no `Value` property.

Instead, in your form, add an addition Hidden Control containing the value of the profile

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnFriend" Value='<%# Eval("ProfileId") %>' />
```

Which you can then use in your button handler code behind:

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FriendProfileId", hdnFriend.Value);
```